# Docker agent cannot run mkdir on /

Tags: docker, jenkins

### Setup

Jenkins pipeline where the agent is docker container, defined in Dockerfile.agent like so :

```
pipeline {

agent {
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile.agent'
        args "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    }
} ...
```

for the Dockerfile.agent i did this :

```
FROM jenkins/agent:latest

USER root

# Install stuff needed for aws
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y awscli default-jdk

# install npm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    npm
# update npm using npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest
# install docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh

# Add the commands to fix npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.npm
RUN chown -R jenkins /home/jenkins/.npm
# fix docker permissions
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

### Problem

Everything runs well, checkout, install, build.

But when it come to docker building the image i get this error in the job console :

```
+ docker build -t my-react-app .
ERROR: mkdir /.docker: permission denied
```

Related stage :

```
    stage("Build Docker Image") {
        steps {
            sh "docker build -t my-react-app  ."
        }
    }
```

I added the jenkins user to the docker group with usermod, what else does it need to run ? i dont get it.